# How can I convert a date into an integer?

Tags: javascript, date

I have an array of dates and have been using the map function to iterate through it, but I can't figure out the JavaScript code for converting them into integers.

This is the array of dates:

```
var dates_as_int = [
    "2016-07-19T20:23:01.804Z",
    "2016-07-20T15:43:54.776Z",
    "2016-07-22T14:53:38.634Z",
    "2016-07-25T14:39:34.527Z"
];
```

Comment: 1. Convert to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), 2. Call [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
var dates = dates_as_int.map(function(dateStr) {
    return new Date(dateStr).getTime();
});
```

=>

```
[1468959781804, 1469029434776, 1469199218634, 1469457574527]
```

---

Update:
ES6 version:

```
const dates = dates_as_int.map(date => new Date(date).getTime())
```

---

The [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method on the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#date_object) returns an “ECMAScript epoch”, which is the same as the UNIX epoch but in **milliseconds**. This is important to note as some other languages use UNIX timestamps which are in in seconds.

The UNIX timestamp and is equivalent to the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970. This is a date you might have seen before in databases or some apps, and it’s usually the sign of a bug.

Comment: After a bit of playing around, I think @Alnitak's answer is actually better, since `Date.parse()` already returns the required integer (i.e., there's no need to also use `getTime()`). For bonus points, I also like the way @Alnitak's snippet has a reference to the `Date.parse` function straight in `Array.map()`. :)

Comment: @MarkBirbeck 3½ years later, I agree! Alnitak’s code is simpler - I would probably write it their way as well. That said, the shortest/simplest code is not the easiest to read. I know that `getTime()` always returns the JavaScript timestamp, but I would have (incorrectly) assumed that `Date.parse` returns a new `Date`, had I read this code in a project

Comment: This code does not throw a type error when using TypeScript for anyone getting annoyed at Date and string not sufficiently overlapping with the other. (Date.parse() does)

Answer (score 27):

Using the builtin [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function which accepts input in ISO8601 format and directly returns the desired integer return value:

```
var dates_as_int = dates.map(Date.parse);
```

Answer (score 24):

Here what you can try:

```
var d = Date.parse("2016-07-19T20:23:01.804Z");
alert(d); //this is in milliseconds
```

Comment: perfect, helps me!

Comment: terseness award winner
```
var dates = dates_as_int.map(Date.parse);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can run it through `Number()`

```
var myInt = Number(new Date(dates_as_int[0]));
```

> If the parameter is a Date object, the Number() function returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC.

[Use of Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

Comment: I believe I made the appropriate changes @AlekseyL.

Comment: Just to add to this, Number calls the valueOf method of the date, which returns the number of milliseconds (same as getTime).

Answer (score 1):

if your format date is YYYY/M/D you can use this code  :

```
let yourDate = momentjs(new Date().toLocaleDateString(), 'M/D/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let newDate = Number(yourDate.slice(0, 10).split('-').join(''));
```