# How to convert datetime to number in sql server

Tags: javascript, sql-server

What is the equivalent sql syntax for this javascript code:

```
let date = new Date();
alert(+date);
```

sample date = "Mon Jan 12 2015 12:15:00 GMT+0800"

```
var dat = new Date("Mon Jan 12 2015 12:15:00 GMT+0800")
console.log(+dat);
```

I am referring to a solution in SQL here.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701847/how-can-i-convert-a-date-into-an-integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server datetime to bigint (epoch) overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634833/sql-server-datetime-to-bigint-epoch-overflow)

Comment: `alert(+date);` returns `1560930169708`, do you want the same output in SQL Server too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a date into an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701847/how-can-i-convert-a-date-into-an-integer)

Comment: @Arulkumar yea you got it

Comment: @nazhannasir I am referring to SQL if there is a workaround getting same value from the javascript code given.
SQL datetime to number/int

Comment: @FrancisLim Please check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44c6ca52b7a50edb609d8b51b762d9b5). Is that the query you are looking for?

Comment: @FrancisLim What does the Javascript Integer do, actually? nr of milliseconds since 1970 or something?

Comment: @Arulkumar https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp not same result

Comment: @steenbergh yea like this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: @FrancisLim The output will be keep on change, becasue it is based on the timestamp too, so for each second the output will be change. In the link, you can click "Try it" continously and it will return different output (atlease last 5 numbers)

Comment: @Arulkumar 
For this one?
var dat = new Date("Mon Jan 12 2015 12:15:00 GMT+0800")
console.log(+dat); -> 1421036100000

Thank You so much!

Comment: @FrancisLim This [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24500104214402d5f0638d051c6aeb9a) can help you, but due to GMT time zone the JavaScript and SQL result are not same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DECLARE @newDate datetime = GetDate()
PRINT CONVERT(varchar(20), @newDate, 103)
```

The 103 parameter determines the format. The full documentation for `CONVERT` and its parameters is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in `SQL-Server` to get the current date.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate = GETDATE()

PRINT @CurrentDate
```

Comment: @FrancisLim DateTime to INT? does that mean only day part?

Comment: var dat = new Date("Mon Jan 12 2015 12:15:00 GMT+0800")
console.log(+dat);

Yea but replicate this result to SQL bro

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01', getdate())
```

This gives the number of seconds between the current time and the start of the Linux Epoch, `1-jan-1970 00:00`.

To break it down:

```
SELECT             -- duh
DATEDIFF           -- Datediff calculates the number of time-units between time A and time B
  (SECOND          -- What type of time unit? Can be month, day, hour or here: Second
  , '1970-01-01'   -- Time A
  , getdate()      -- Time B, SQL's built-in current date function
)
```

Note that this drops the milliseconds, but we can add those back in by just grabbing the mill's off of the current time:

```
select concat(datediff(SECOND, '1970-01-01', getdate()), datepart(millisecond, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE()) AS BIGINT)*1000
```